# Attempt to read property "POST /padcenter/store

Tags: laravel-8

Attempt to read property "POST /padcenter/store HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-

**Attempt to read property "POST /padcenter/store HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-**

Answer (score 0):

I had this:

```
'category_name'->$request->category_name
```

Instead of this:

```
'category_name'=>$request->category_name
```

Just by replacing `->` with `=>`, I fixed this error.